# how to resolve docker throwing Error on Centos 7 VM

Tags: azure, docker, centos, centos7

I have installed docker on my centos 7 VM running on Azure. I used below commands to install docker:
`sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin`

After successfully installing docker, I'm getting below error. Can someone please suggest what could be the problem.

```
sudo docker --version
runtime: s.allocCount= 37 s.nelems= 73
fatal error: s.allocCount != s.nelems && freeIndex == s.nelems

goroutine 1 [running, locked to thread]:
runtime.throw({0x562d045c5c70?, 0x7fb997110112?})
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:992 +0x71 fp=0xc0001def58 sp=0xc0001def28 pc=0x562d032fb1d1
runtime.(*mcache).nextFree(0x7fb997110108, 0x12)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:884 +0x1e5 fp=0xc0001defa0 sp=0xc0001def58 pc=0x562d032d3085
runtime.mallocgc(0x70, 0x562d04d1cea0, 0x1)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1085 +0x4e5 fp=0xc0001df018 sp=0xc0001defa0 pc=0x562d032d35a5
runtime.newobject(0x562d04c463a0?)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/malloc.go:1259 +0x27 fp=0xc0001df040 sp=0xc0001df018 pc=0x562d032d3ae7
regexp/syntax.(*Regexp).Simplify(0xc00023ccb0)
        /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/simplify.go:98 +0x945 fp=0xc0001df150 sp=0xc0001df040 pc=0x562d036194c5
regexp/syntax.(*Regexp).Simplify(0xc00023cd20)
        /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/simplify.go:23 +0x4cc fp=0xc0001df260 sp=0xc0001df150 pc=0x562d0361904c
regexp/syntax.(*Regexp).Simplify(0xc00023cb60)
        /usr/local/go/src/regexp/syntax/simplify.go:23 +0x4cc fp=0xc0001df370 sp=0xc0001df260 pc=0x562d0361904c
```

I removed docker completely and installed again. But got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

*I tried to reproduce the same issue in my environment and got the below results*

*I have created the Centos-vm and I tried to install the docker into the Centos*

```
sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin
```

*When I use the above command I got the appropriate results*

[image]

*In the docker module it self there is no packages available so docker it will show successfully installed but it will not run*

*I have used the below command to install the docker*

```
sudo yum update check-update
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

*Docker installed successfully*

[image]

*Here is my docker version*

[image]

*I am able to start my docker and the docker status is in active*

```
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo systemctl status docker
```

[image]

*NOTE: This error will happen with the old versions also please try to install the latest version of the docker*